# PHP function to check if something valid or return error message

Tags: php, error-handling

I would like to make a function that checks if something is valid, but if it can't then I want to return an error message that will probably be used to to throw an exception.

```php
public function isTodayWithinDateRange(\DateTime $start, \DateTime $end) {
    $now = new \DateTime();
    if($now >= $start && $now <= $end) return true;
    if($now < $start) return 'Today is before the start date';
    if($now > $end) return 'Today is later than the end date';
}
```

And would probably use within a foreach as a validation check such as...

```php
if(isTodayWithinDateRange($myStart, $myEnd) !== true) {
    throw new Exception(isTodayWithinDateRange($myStart, $myEnd));
}
```

Is this a good way to go about it?  I thought about putting the exception within the function, but this doesn't seem right as all that function should be doing is doing a check and the thing calling it should decide if an error is exceptional or not.

I also thought about returning an array such as...

```php
    return array(
        'success' => false,
        'error' => 'Today is later than the end date'
    );
```

But I would expect isTodayWithinDateRange to return `true` if the answer is 'yes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply , the method **isTodayWithinDateRange** can throw the exception in this case since the responsability of the method is to check the constraint . 
So , i think that you can try it as :

```
function isTodayWithinDateRange(\DateTime $start, \DateTime $end) {
  $now = new \DateTime();
  if($now < $start) throw new Excception('Today is before the start date') ;
  if($now > $end) throw new Exception('Today is later than the end date');  
  return true;

}
```

First , start with case where you are looking to throw exception , in this case , it's not clearly , but think about a case where you have a lot of logic , here you should start with cases where you don't need to manipulate your logic (like if the argument is null , or missing ...) .

Call you  method as :

```
$myStart = new Datetime('01-06-2012');
$myEnd = new Datetime('01-06-2020');

// loop 

try{

if(isTodayWithinDateRange($myStart, $myEnd)) {
 echo 'contraint validated';

}
}catch(Exception $e){

    echo $e->getMessage();
}
//end loop
```

I hope this help you .

Comment: This is what I would have answered, but `isTodayWithinDateRange()` does not need to return `true` nor does it need to be inside a `if (...)` because it will only return when today is in the date range. I would also change the name to `validateTodayIsWithinDateRange()`, or something similar.

Comment: Returning _true_ vs throwing an error is a pattern I've seen before in frameworks in other languages. Not sure whether this goes against php guidelines though.

Comment: @dfhwze It is common pratice to let a function return something. That's regarded better than not returning anything. So, I have no real problem with returning true here, but the code here almost seems to suggest the function could return false, which it cannot.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Java uses this pattern in _add_ methods in collections: http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/AbstractQueue-source.html. Just to show that the pattern is not that uncommon.

Comment: @dfhwze But do you ever see something like `if (s.add("Welcome")) { ... }` in Java? What if an `else` block is added to that `if (...)`? It won't ever work.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You are correct. It all depends on a good specification of the method to know how to call it.